# springboot swagger3 "Failed to load remote configuration."

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

Spring Boot 2.6.3 with Springdoc.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

In `applicaton.yaml`, when I set the path as /v3/api-docs or remove it, that means use the default path "/v3/api-docs".
The Swagger UI page shows up correctly with the APIs
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

But I want to overite the path as below

```
  api-docs.path: /bus/v3/api-docs
```

then Swagger UI displays the "Failed to load remote configuration" error:

[image: load api list error]

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71857622/java-spring-boot-with-swagger-failed-to-load-remote-configuration/72541309#72541309

Answer (score 40):

```
Make sure to add "/v3/api-docs/**" in configure method.
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "
/v3/api-docs/**");
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your answer differ from Amir Pezeshk answer?

Comment: Awesome adding "antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**") worked for me. I have Spring boot 2.6.7 and openapi 1.6.9, Thank you @Aamma

Comment: oh, thanks. This helps also to have "/v3/api-docs" already written in the "Explore" textfield. Till now I lost my mind to have again the Swagger-ui after the migration an I always had as defaukt the petshop documentation. I have Spring boot 2.7.4 and springdoc.openapi 1.6.11

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem, If you are behind a reverse proxy, the fix was to add the following property  in application.yml

```
server:
  forward-headers-strategy: framework
```

this is needed due to the following

Swagger relies on internal routing to make requests from the clients perspective. Putting the service behind a reverse-proxy without providing the X-Forwarded headers will result in the user not being able to use the documentation as intended

source -> https://medium.com/swlh/swagger-spring-boot-2-with-a-reverse-proxy-in-docker-8a8795aa3da4

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: Worked for me. I also needed to add the X-Forwarded-Prefix header in my reverse proxy. See here: https://springdoc.org/index.html#how-can-i-deploy-springdoc-openapi-ui-behind-a-reverse-proxy

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Spring Security in your app, you must include the URL in the configs.
Add the code below please to your project.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/bus/v3/api-docs/**");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you recently updated, you may have `v2` ignored but not `v3`.

Answer (score 10):

Perform "Empty cache and hard refresh" in your browser.

Answer (score 5):

I think I have solved the problem (thanks to @Ivan Zaitsev), just wanted to add more clarification to the answer.

I too have changed the api-docs.path property and I had the same problem. When I inspect the requests on swagger UI page, swagger-config request returns 404 since it was still trying to get the config from the old URL.

Even though I have changed api-docs.path property, here is the request URL that tries to retrieve swagger-config.
http://localhost:8080/api/v3/api-docs/swagger-config

It turned out to be a problem related to openapi-ui, because I was able to solve it when I cleared the browser cache and cookies. It is better do to the tests with incognito browser since it does not hold any data on the session.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `org.spring framework.security:spring-security-config:6.1.3`, this would be able to help you.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurity {
    @Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
   
        http.authorizeHttpRequests {
            it.requestMatchers(antMatcher("/swagger-ui/**")).permitAll()
            it.requestMatchers(antMatcher("/api-docs/**")).permitAll()
            it.anyRequest().authenticated()
        }
        return http.build()
    }
 
}
```

application.yml

```
springdoc:
    swagger-ui:
        enabled: true
        path: /swagger-ui.html
    api-docs.path: /api-docs
```

Answer (score 2):

It's old question but when I was looking for answer I came here, so after I make it work with newer version, I decided to share my answer, maybe someone find it useful.

This is my implementation for spring security - 3.1.0 and openApi 2.1.0 with gradle:

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:3.1.0"
implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0"
```

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**",
                        "/swagger-resources/*",
                        "/v3/api-docs/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

You need to specify paths in requestMatcher like "/bus/v3/api-docs".
The best option is to implement it one by one:

- check if "/**" works, then
- check if /bus/** works (in my case matcher with default path "/api" which is set for whole project and whole path looked like this - /api/swagger-ui/** didn't work, but /swagger-ui/** worked)
- then another check if /bus/v3/** work

**  - two stars are wildcard.

Even my path for swagger looks like this: api/swagger-ui/index.html#/
I needed to add matcher: v3/api-docs/** to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, spring-boot app was deployed behind a reverse proxy and the reverse-proxy had a context-root.

in localhost everything was working fine because the swagger would be on
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html
and this would load http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs/swagger-config fine

But when it was hosted on the test-server, the url will change to
https://something.com/my-app/swagger-ui/index.html and this would load
https://something.com/v3/api-docs/swagger-config instead of [https://something.com/**my-app**/v3/api-docs/swagger-config](https://something.com/my-app/v3/api-docs/swagger-config)

the following in application.properties fixed it

```
server.forward-headers-strategy=framework
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **SpringBoot v3**, you must use **springdoc-openapi v2**:

https://springdoc.org/v2/

With gradle, for example:

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this code in SecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
             http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .deny()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(getPermitAll()).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll();
    }
```

The AUTH_WHITELIST like this:

```
private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        "/v2/api-docs",
        "/swagger-resources",
        "/swagger-resources/**",
        "/configuration/ui",
        "/configuration/security",
        "/swagger-ui.html",
        "/webjars/**",
        "/v3/api-docs/**",
        "/swagger-ui/**"
};
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Good.

Answer (score 0):

The change from `/v3/api-docs` to `/v3/api-docs/**` ensures that any additional path segments are also matched, which is necessary for Swagger's dynamic documentation generation to work properly.

"/v3/api-docs", made it to fail but  "/v3/api-docs/**" made it to work,

This is because, `/v3/api/docs` would only match exactly that path, but `/v3/api/docs` will allow for additional paths. It also ensures that any additional path segments are also matched, which is necessary for Swagger's dynamic documentation generation to work properly.

Comment: This fixed my error completely, and now swagger docs working smilingly.