# java Spring Boot with Swagger - Failed to load remote configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I have a Java 11 Spring Boot 2.5.1 application.

**Swagger works locally via http:**

I have added Swagger, which works perfectly on my localhost:

http://localhost:8085/swagger-ui/index.html#/

[image]

**Swagger does not work remotely via https:**

However, when I deploy it to a remote server, I get the following error:

https://mycompany.co/pow-wow/swagger-ui/index.html#/

[image]

**Error**

> Failed to load remote configuration.

note: the remote server is accessed via https.

The REST endpoints are accessible on the remote server.

e.g. GET https://mycompany.co/pow-wow/powwow/test-me returns a 200 as expected.

**Question**

How do I access the Swagger via the remote server?

**Code**

**pom.xml**

```
    <!-- Swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/powwow/*").hasRole("USER").and().httpBasic();
        //http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*").permitAll().and().httpBasic();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/soapWS/**").permitAll().and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll().and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .httpBasic().and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

**More info:**

When looking at the network traffic in the browser when accessing Swagger.

Locally, there  is a call to:

http://localhost:8085/v3/api-docs/swagger-config

returns:

[image]

```
{"configUrl":"/v3/api-docs/swagger-config","oauth2RedirectUrl":"http://localhost:8085/swagger-ui/oauth2-redirect.html","url":"/v3/api-docs","validatorUrl":""}
```

Remotely, there  is a call to:

https://mycompany.co/v3/api-docs/swagger-config

which returns a `302`.

[image]

But https://mycompany.co/pow-wow/v3/api-docs/swagger-config

returns:

```
{"configUrl":"/v3/api-docs/swagger-config","oauth2RedirectUrl":"http://localhost:8085/swagger-ui/oauth2-redirect.html","url":"/v3/api-docs","validatorUrl":""}
```

So this suggests the issue is related to the `/pow-wow` context path is missing in the call.

Comment: Why did you reach the conclusion that HTTPS is the cause?
Also, see SO with similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70906081/springboot-swagger3-failed-to-load-remote-configuration

Comment: @johnnyaug, thank you for your reply.  I had actually read that post before I posted my question.  I tried the suggestions in it (e.g. same as Mohamed's answer below), to no avail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try and add

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    config-url: /pow-wow/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
    url: /v3/api-docs
```

to your application.properties. In your provided example

```
https://mycompany.co/pow-wow/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
```

it shows that you have "/pow-wow/" in your path. Swagger needs to know where to fetch its config.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  That makes sense, but I thought the `application.properties` requires key value pairs. e.g. `abc=wyz`.  I am not sure how to add the above to `application.properties`?

Comment: i  wil try: `springdoc.swagger-ui.config-url=/pow-wow/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/v3/api-docs`

Answer (score 3):

Try to add this as well to your security config class

```java
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
   web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**");
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mohamed, thank you for your suggestion.  I tried this, and unfortunately it has made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If security config allow swagger, it's because of cashing, try it after clear browser cash or in browser **incognito mode**.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue :

- with `mvn spring-boot:run` : OK
- on my local Tomcat server : OK
- on the Tomcat server of my organization : KO (Failed to load remote configuration)

The cause was the reverse proxy of my organization that blocked the loop-back call of the application.

Answer (score 0):

To those who are asking:

I had the same issue and this video helped me check it out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_RWUcTqHBI

Just simple step by step.

Regarding my project to be on the same page:

Spring Boot 3 + Spring Security.

So I:

1. Added "/swagger-ui/**" and "/v3/api-docs/**" as @Mohamed suggested to my SecurityFilterChain bean.
2. Added springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui dependency in POM.
3. Configurated SwaggerConfig as follow:

```
@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition
public class SwaggerConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI config() {
        return new OpenAPI().info(
                new Info()
                        .title("")
                        .version("")
                        .description("")
        );
    }
}
```

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html#/

And it worked smoothly!

Answer (score 0):

Config that helped me:

```
springdoc:
    swagger-ui:
        configUrl: /your-service/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
        url: /your-service/v3/api-docs
```

If you have problems with the try it out block (404 error, wrong url), then just use the @OpenAPIDefinition annotation. Kotlin example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@OpenAPIDefinition(
    info = Info(title = "Your Service API", version = "1.0", description = "Your service description"),
    servers = [Server(url = "/your-service", description = "Your Service")]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and managed to solve it.

If you have configured your spring security with `.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()` and still get this error then it means that the URL - `/swagger-ui/index.html#/` is accessible but the network calls that are made on that page are probably being blocked by spring security.
Check the network tab in the browser and make sure all the networks calls are permitted without authentication.

Generally, `.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()` is sufficient but in my case I had path prefix set to `api/v1` hence I modified my code to `.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/api/v1/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Few points for those who are working in Spring webflux.

1. You can use the openAPI dependency shared below. No other dependency is needed for this.

> org.springdoc
>         springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui
>         2.3.0

2. I found out that the path under api-docs field should end with .yaml extension . Otherwise the swagger ui won't come up.
3. If you're running it in local, you only need below config and the @OpenAPIDefinition annotation in the main class and it will be able to pick all the Controllers. But it won't pick the Functional endpoints(Just FYI. For that you need to manually write API docs definition under annotation @RouterOperations. I will share a link where it is explained easily and beautifully).

> ```
> springdoc:
>   api-docs:
>     path: /swagger-doc/v3/api-docs.yaml
>     groups:
>       enabled: true
>   swagger-ui:
>     path: /swagger-doc/swagger-ui.html
> ```

3. If you want to put it in higher env, you should add config-url and url fields as well under swagger-ui field. The config is provided below.

> ```
> springdoc:
>   api-docs:
>     path: /swagger-doc/v3/api-docs.yaml
>     groups:
>       enabled: true
>   swagger-ui:
>     config-url: /<something-AFTER-hostname>/<application-context-path>/swagger-doc/v3/api-docs.yaml/swagger-config
>     url: /<something-AFTER-hostname>/<application-context-path>/swagger-doc/v3/api-docs.yaml
>     path: /swagger-doc/swagger-ui.html
> ```

For example, say your higher env url is like https://host.company.com/customerhelp/helpdesk/api_v1
where https://host.company.com/customerhelp portion is attached by the company infra(may be when Kubernetes is used to deploy services), /helpdesk is the application context path and /api_v1 is an api endpoint.

The config-url will become like:

> `/customerhelp/helpdesk/swagger-doc/v3/api-docs.yaml/swagger-config`

And url will become:

> `/customerhelp/helpdesk/swagger-doc/v3/api-docs.yaml`

Here's the YT link that helped me understanding how to write apiDocs for Functional endpoints.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEtgsJETiTQ&lc=Ugx1wMzR31ESKXeOnMt4AaABAg.A-Tn0aUYQM9A-Tpo1k6SwT