# Getting "Failed to load remote configuration" when trying to access swagger-ui.html

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

When I try to access the swagger APIs, I receive "Failed to load remote configuration". I have upgraded springfox swagger to springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui. I am using springboot version 3.1.16 and java 17 . However, I'm not sure what endpoints should be added to the WHITELIST, after updating.
Note: i only had one docket, so i have added the GroupedOpenApi.

```
   @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi apiDescription() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .group("Info Service")
                .pathsToMatch("/.*")
                .build();
    }
```

Updated the above code to :

```
 @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi apiDescription() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("Service").pathsToMatch("/.*")
                .packagesToScan("org.springframework.boot").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI().info(new Info().title(getApiTitle()).description(getApiDescription()).version(version))
                .externalDocs(new ExternalDocumentation().description("swagger"));
    }
```

Now i am able to access the link:  **https://addreess/api/v3/api-docs**

But for the links: **https://addreess/api/swagger-ui/index.html** and **https://addreess/api/swagger-ui.html**
it is showing ->> **Failed to load remote configuration.**

Below is my current WHITELIST.

```
 private static final String[] WHITELIST = {
            // -- Swagger UI v2
            "/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**",
            // -- Swagger UI v3 (OpenAPI)
            "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**"
            // other public endpoints of your API may be appended to this array
    };
```

POM:

```
<dependencies>         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat-embed.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat-embed.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat-embed.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.agileware</groupId>
            <artifactId>smartunit</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
            <artifactId>system-lambda</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Postgres -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Could you share also `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` file with dependencies that you have added ? Also  add `"/swagger-ui.html"`  to WHITELIST

Comment: @AndreiLisa Thanks for your response, please find my pom file

Comment: after checking your problem and code that you provide I guess you will be able to find a solution of the problem on this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71857622/java-spring-boot-with-swagger-failed-to-load-remote-configuration)

Comment: Also when you start the application do you see this king of message in logs `This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.` ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa no don't find any messages like above in the logs. But currently i see errors like ---Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space] with root cause

Comment: then you should fix it and then also remove that I gave in an answer, because after fix you will not be able to see all routes of your controllers

Answer (score 0):

As a fix to your problem just remove next one `Configuration`:

```
@Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi apiDescription() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("Service").pathsToMatch("/.*")
                .packagesToScan("org.springframework.boot").build();
    }
```

It is not necessary in your case.

Comment: so just OpenApi is enough?

Comment: yes, it is enough.